# Any damage to Water heater when main water shut-off for a prolonged vacation in Texas

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Any damage to Water heater in the attic, if main water to the house is shut off for a month when owner on vacation, please? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Gas or electric WH?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. While the water was off, was the water heater left on? Was any water drawn while the water was turned off?

Comment: Mines were gas WH.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I kept my WH at the pilot setting. How do we know if it draws water when the valve is shut off?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no damage, but of course this would be non-freezing conditions. What setting would you leave the heater on? If electric, I would say switch off power to the heater. If gas, switch to vacation/pilot setting or even turn gas off at the heater.

Upon return I would turn the heater to hot (140 F) and let it come to temperature, then run hot through all delivery points.

Comment: Thank you. We will turn the setting to pilot, cutting off the ice-maker and turn  refrig. to low setting. And shut off the main water valve. Is there other thing to do; off for one month in Late September and Texas weather, no deep freeze?

Comment: Are you shutting off the water at the city meter or with your own valve?

Comment: Hi Jim. We will shut off water to the house. Will keep water from the main city meter on because of sprinkle system.